# How convert png to av1 with alpha channel

Tags: ffmpeg

I want convert png to webm (av1), but loss the alpha channel.
'ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i %04d.png -c:v libaom-av1 -pix_fmt yuva420p -crf 30 output.webm'

Comment: There is a warning message: `Incompatible pixel format 'yuva420p' for codec 'libaom-av1', auto-selecting format 'yuv420p'`. Executing `ffmpeg -h encoder=libaom-av1` lists  the supported pixel formats. None of the formats include alpha. It looks like `libaom-av1` encoder doesn't support alpha channel.